# switch from left to right

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, arabic, right-to-left

I am translating some articles to Arabic
[image]

but when switch the bibliography to language English
it is also switched in the table of contents
I have to switch the bibliography to English to make it from left to right (because Arabic is from right to left)
how to solve this problem in the table of contents

```
\selectlanguage{english}
 {\renewcommand\bibname{المراجع}
\printbibliography

}
```

Comment: Did you search here for tag [arabic] ? May be there has been answered a similar question already.

Comment: ¿With `pdftex`, `xetex`, `luatex`? ¿With `babel`, `arabxetex`, `polyglossia`...?

Comment: babel and luatex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, it was because the references were in English so I had to switch let the title only in Arabic

```
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\renewcommand\bibname{المراجع}
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\selectlanguage{english}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```